# ubuntu-application-switcher

Tags: macbuntu

After following this [guideline](http://www.noobslab.com/2016/04/macbuntu-1604-transformation-pack-for.html) my Ubuntu application switcher would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Yl0.jpg). It seemed like there are 2 application switchers getting overlapped. Anybody has any idea on this, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have two independent application switchers running in parallel, so you may want to disable/uninstall one, or re-assign keyboard shortcuts.

To change shortcuts for the default switcher, you can use the Unity Tweak Tool (`sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`). After opening it, click on "Switcher" and adjust "Window switching shortcuts".

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I figured it out that I also installed Compiz Settings Manager which caused conflicts with Unity Tweak Tool. Then I went to Compiz Settings Manager > Ubuntu Unity Plugin, disabled it and enabled it, conflict detection would come and after they got resolved all came back to normal. Some steps I'd like to share.
Many thanks again :)